# Angular pagination column sort across all pages client side

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting

I'm trying to get this to work and seeing if there is an quick easy solution - right now I have a table that I'm doing paging and sorting through all on the client side. Currently on the load of the page I am setting the default sort by date, however there are 2 other columns that can be clicked and sorted. It is working but only on the page that it is currently viewed on, does not trickle down to the other pages. Here's my sort function and paging function. Appreciate any help!

```
    $scope.sortBy = function(keyName){
        if($scope.sortType === keyName){
            $scope.sortReverse = !$scope.sortReverse;
        } else{
            $scope.sortReverse = false;
        }
        $scope.sortType = keyName;
        console.log('Type', $scope.sortType, 'Reverse', $scope.sortReverse);
    };

    function setPage(page) {
        if (page < 1 || page > vm.pager.totalPages) {
            return;
        }

        // get pager object from service
        vm.pager = PagerService.GetPager(vm.uploads.length, page);

        // get current page of items
        vm.uploads.sort(function(a,b){
            return new Date(b.uploadDate).getTime()- new Date(a.uploadDate).getTime();
        })

        vm.items = vm.uploads.slice(vm.pager.startIndex, vm.pager.endIndex + 1);
    }
```

Here is the html table code:

```
                <div>
                    <table class="table">
                        <tr>
                            <th ng-click="sortBy('uploadDate')" >Upload Date
                                <span ng-show="sortType == 'uploadDate' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
                                <span ng-show="sortType == 'uploadDate' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
                            </th>
                            <th>Product</th>
                            <th>Comments</th>
                            <th ng-click="sortBy('templateName')">Template
                                <span ng-show="sortType == 'templateName' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
                                <span ng-show="sortType == 'templateName' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
                            </th>
                            <th>Last Updated By</th>
                            <th>Last Updated</th>
                            <th ng-click="sortBy(statusName)">Status
                                <span ng-show="sortType == 'statusName' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
                                <span ng-show="sortType == 'statusName' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
                            </th>
                            <th>Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr ng-repeat="upload in vm.items | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse">
                            <td style="white-space: nowrap;">{{upload.uploadDate}}</td>
                            <td>{{upload.product}}</td>
                            <td style="white-space: nowrap;">{{upload.comments}}</td>
                            <td style="white-space: nowrap;">{{upload.templateName}}</td>
                            <td style="white-space: nowrap;">{{upload.lastUpdatedByUser}}</td>
                            <td style="white-space: nowrap;">{{upload.lastUpdateDate}}</td>
                            <td style="white-space: nowrap;">{{upload.status.statusName}}</td>
                            <td>
                                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs pull-left" style="margin-bottom: 5px; " ng-hide="upload.status.statusCd === 'NEW' || upload.status.statusCd === 'ERROR'" ng-click="vm.loadStagingPage(upload.dataLoadExecutionId, upload.product, upload.status)">View</button>
                                <span class="btn btn-primary btn-xs pull-left" style="margin-bottom: 5px; " type="button" ng-click="vm.cancelDataExecution(upload.dataLoadExecutionId)" ng-show="upload.inProgress || upload.status.statusCd === 'ERROR'">Remove</span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                <div class="text-center">
                   <ul ng-if="vm.pager.pages.length" class="pagination">
                        <li ng-class="{disabled:vm.pager.currentPage === 1}">
                            <a ng-click="vm.setPage(1)">First</a>
                        </li>
                        <li ng-class="{disabled:vm.pager.currentPage === 1}">
                            <a ng-click="vm.setPage(vm.pager.currentPage - 1)">Previous</a>
                        </li>
                        <li ng-repeat="page in vm.pager.pages" ng-class="{active:vm.pager.currentPage === page}">
                            <a ng-click="vm.setPage(page)">{{page}}</a>
                        </li>               
                        <li ng-class="{disabled:vm.pager.currentPage === vm.pager.totalPages}">
                            <a ng-click="vm.setPage(vm.pager.currentPage + 1)">Next</a>
                        </li>
                        <li ng-class="{disabled:vm.pager.currentPage === vm.pager.totalPages}">
                            <a ng-click="vm.setPage(vm.pager.totalPages)">Last</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you return to page 1 when changing sortType?

Comment: Can you post the HTML table code? Where else are you using `$scope.sortBy`?

Comment: Just posted the html code, I'm only using the sortBy here - and yes, it actually should return to page 1 when sortType is changed, I did not think about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must sort the collection based on `$scope.sortType` before splicing your current page.

It's also better if you return to page 1 when changing the `$scope.sortType`

```
$scope.sortBy = function(keyName){
    var changedSortType = $scope.sortType === keyName;
    $scope.sortType = keyName;
    if(changedSortType){
        $scope.sortReverse = !$scope.sortReverse;
    } else{
        $scope.sortReverse = false;
        setPage(1);
    }

    console.log('Type', $scope.sortType, 'Reverse', $scope.sortReverse);
};

function setPage(page) {
    if (page < 1 || page > vm.pager.totalPages) {
        return;
    }

    // get pager object from service
    vm.pager = PagerService.GetPager(vm.uploads.length, page);

    // get current page of items
    vm.uploads.sort(function(a,b){
        // here you should sort based on $scope.sortType
        var result;
        switch($scope.sortType) {
            case 'uploadDate':
                result = new Date(b.uploadDate).getTime()- new Date(a.uploadDate).getTime();
                break;
            case 'templateName':
                if(a.templateName < b.templateName) result = -1;
                if(a.templateName > b.templateName) result = 1;
                result = 0;
                break;
            // ...
        }
        if ($scope.sortReverse) {
            result *= -1;
        }
        return result;
    })

    vm.items = vm.uploads.slice(vm.pager.startIndex, vm.pager.endIndex + 1);
}
```

Comment: for templateName - before the break do I need to add any logic? I just need it to sort alphabetically. sorry i'm pretty new to this

Comment: I just edited my response with an example for comparing templateName alphabetically. Basically, you must return a negative number if `a` comes before `b`, `zero` if they are equal, and a positive number if `a` comes after `b`

Comment: Thank you - this should work even if the sort is applied on the first page correct? and should sort the entire list across all pages?

Comment: Yes, just remember to initialize `$scope.sortType` with the default value (uploadDate) **before** calling `setPage` for the first time.

Comment: I did that at the top of my controller already. It also is still only sorting based on the values on each page, not the entire list on all pages

Comment: It still is only sorting the results just on that page

Comment: Even after changing the sort type or the page? I had forgotten to take the $scope.sortReverse into account, and have edited the response to fix that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118450/discussion-between-buccaneer-and-drigoangelo).